# read traffic/bandwidth usage by protocol

Tags: snmp, fortigate, fortinet, netflow

I need to analyze the traffic of a Fortigate Firewall in my program.

Currently, I can read the overall traffic using SNMP.

The problem is that I need to analyze the type of traffic (HTTP, video streaming etc.) too.

Is this possible using SNMP or do I need to use another protocol like NetFlow, Packet Sniffer or xFlow and what do I need to look for(e.g. what OIDs)?

I am using the Firmware Version `v5.2.13,build762 (GA)`.

Does anybody know a protocol that I can use for this?

Comment: The Fortigate specifically provides information about that through Fortiguard - by protocol, source, destination, application, ... Also, 5.x firmware is ancient.

Comment: I know that the version is old but I have that firewall to test it. I may be able to update it if it is required but I am not sure. Can I read that information automatically in my program?

Comment: You'd need to add the developer API to your subscription, sadly it's not public. FortiAnalyzer should also be able to export what you need. Another option is to log externally (via syslog) and analyze that (that's what we do). We also use sFlow (on the core switch) for a quick overview.

Comment: What can I use that is available publicly?

Comment: Does it support Netflow?

Comment: There is an option `netflow-sampler` in `config system interface` so I guess.